# How to Deploy VB6 Applications?

Tags: vb6

How to run the exe file to other system?

Using VB 6

I copied the exe file to other system, then run that exe file, it not working it showing error 
“component comdlg32.ocx or one its dependencies not correctly registered a file is missing or invalid”`

Can any one help me how to avoid this error?

Comment: More vb6 install options in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23836/how-to-create-a-simple-install-system-for-vb6-on-xp-vista

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When deploying VB6 applications, you should create a Setup, this will manage the DLL's that the VB6 application depends on. Since it is not enough to just copy the .Exe and .Dll's. You also need to register them.

The creation of the setup is included in the VB6 environment.

Comment: It's been a long time since I had a running VB6 environment. Read this for more information: http://visualbasic.about.com/od/quicktips/qt/vb6pack_deploy_wiz2.htm, or search google for "VB6 create setup.Exe"

Comment: Actually, because of the difficulty we had deploying VB6, we decided to use .Net. Life (at least deployment) will be much easier when you use VB.Net.

Comment: How to do this ?

Answer (score 2):

You can read this [http://support.microsoft.com/kb/830761](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/290887) which is very comprehensive.

[1](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/290887): http://support.microsoft.com/kb/830761 for more information.

Or if you just want the redistributable files check this kb http://support.microsoft.com/kb/290887

Comment: Your first link says quite explicitly: "The VBRun60sp6.exe file is not intended to replace the Package and Deployment Wizard (PDW) for distributing Visual Basic applications."

Comment: All links have expired. Links 1 and 3 now point to the same place, which is Download of VB6 SP6 runtimes. Link 2 is dead.

Answer (score 1):

Copy and register the comdlg32.ocx on other system. Link: [Fix Missing Comdlg32.ocx Run time Error in Portable apps](http://blogote.com/2009/windows-ideas/fix-missing-comdlg32ocx-run-time-error-in-portable-apps.html).

Create an installer for your program.

Comment: This link is dead.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are deploying your program to really old versions of Windows (prior to XP), one nice alternative is to create an XCopy package using reg-free COM.  This is fairly easy for most simple programs using [Make My Manifest](http://mmm4vb6.atom5.com/) though it can be done by hand or using other tools if you invest in a little study.

Even then a formal installer package is usually desireable though, if nothing else to create Start Menu shortcuts and set up application workspace directories.

Keep in mind that even the PDWizard is difficult to use blindly.  Packaging and deployment is a topic that requires some learning investment.

Answer (score 0):

Outdated or missing comdlg32.ocx runtime library is causing this error. Here is a copy of [comdlg32.ocx](http://windowsxp.mvps.org/utils/Comdlg32.zip) (~60 Kb Zip). Download the file to the Desktop and extract the comdlg32.ocx to your the Windows\System32 folder.

Note: If you already have a copy of comdlg32.ocx, backup the existing file to a different folder and delete it from System32 folder.

```
1. Download comdlg32.zip and save to Desktop.

2. Unzip the file using WinZip or any other utility.

3. Extract comdlg32.ocx to Windows\System32 folder.

4. Type the following command from Start, Run dialog:
```

**regsvr32  %Systemroot%\System32\comdlg32.ocx**

Answer (score 0):

Typically a VB 6 app will consist of an `.exe` some `.dll` libraries and a `config.ini` file. The exe is the starting place and it consumes the dll's and config.ini and other resources to run => you have to have all parts in the same directory for the app to run typically called "packaging" an app. E.g. An installer simply ensures that all those files in a packaged app are placed on a users computer in an Windows application directory, and creates a shortcut launch icon so that a user can click the shortcut in the start bar and the app will run.

To "package" your app (put the dll's and exe in the same folder) you can use an Add-In called "Package and Deployment Wizard":
[image]

And here is a demo of using it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XT7jaoAiKDo
You can either package and create an installer and package or just create a package:
[image]

Now if the Deployment Wizard doesnt show as an add-in on your VB6 Editor Installation, go to editor's program folder and find the tools Tools folder, i.e:
[image]

Then you should be able to find the Deployment Wizard there:

[image]

Open it to use it.