# Dependencies for VB6 application

Tags: vb6, dependencies

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to Deploy VB6 Applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1086370/how-to-deploy-vb6-applications)

The company I'm working for has this application that was written in VB6 last year.  I've had the pleasure of working through just a few minor things here and there in it.  However, now I've had a bit of a stumble.  In the latest Visual Studios, whenever you build your application, any referenced .dll dependencies can be found in the bin/Debug(or Release) folder.

My question is that in the VB6 Enterprise IDE, where does the dependencies get placed when you  make the .exe?  I'd assume that they are in the same location as the .exe; however, when I copy that entire folder over to another computer, and regsver32 (in administrator mode, of course), and I try to run the program, I get told I'm missing a dependency.  Thanks for any and all help.

Comment: Other options for vb6 deployment in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23836/how-to-create-a-simple-install-system-for-vb6-on-xp-vista

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's been a while since I worked in VB but I seem to remember that you wouldn't copy the executable but would create an installation package that would manage all the DLL's, OCX's and such and register the necessary things with the registry for you.

Comment: Yes, simply compiling an executable will produce just the EXE file, not any DLLs or anything. Creating an installation package will include all the necessary libraries... for the most part. In my experience, the installation package never worked properly so I had to manually find the missing items and register them. VB6 can be a big pain in a cloaca from deployment perspective. Good luck with deployment OP!

Comment: Again, it's been 10 years but I remember having to muck around with the deployment package code in order to customize the installation because thing's were getting missed or done in the wrong order.  I'm pretty sure that's why people went to third party installation products like Wise.