# installer package for visual basic

Tags: vb6

How can I create the .msi package for visual Basic 6.0. I tried to search internet, but found only how to create the installer package for .net. I want it for Visual basic 6.0.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: It's kind of a duplicate of [How to Deploy VB6 Applications?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1086370/11683), but that question is not really helpful. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa733687(v=vs.60).aspx might or might not be more helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft's native way of creating .msi files in VB6 was by using the Visual Studio Installer Add-in.  That's what I used back in the day.
You might still be able to find it online somewhere.  I googled around looking for a download for some time and wasn't able to find one.

The other option that might do in a pinch is the package and deployment wizard, although I always found it to be rather hard to work with.  If you're not careful to avoid installing certain protected DLL's you can get caught in serious DLL Hell.  I generally used the Installer add-in.

Jim Mack's solution is increasingly popular as support for VB6-specific tools wanes away into nothingness.

Answer (score 2):

[Inno Setup](http://www.innosetup.com/isdl.php) is a very good (free) installer for VB6, and if you must have an MSI you can find a [converter](http://www.exemsi.com/inno-setup-and-msi) to wrap an Inno EXE with an MSI wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

I recently went through the same struggle as you.  Your best option for VB6 is to purchase a third-party package to create the msi.  A google search for "Windows Installer" or "MSI Installer" should get you started.

Here is a discussion on the various options:

[What installation product to use? InstallShield, WiX, Wise, Advanced Installer, etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1544292/what-installation-product-to-use-installshield-wix-wise-advanced-installer?noredirect=1&lq=1)