# How can I setup the VB project?

Tags: vb6, installation

Using VB6

I want to setup the Project, Last time I used VB 6 Package and Deployment wizard.  It asks to modify some system file. I modified my system file, and then it worked.  Now again I want to setup my new project, is asking to change the system file.

Once I set up the project, is asking to change the system file and crystal report files (like crystl32.ocx… etc)

Is showing error like, “out of stack space”, “out of system date” etc...

Why is always asking to change?

What is best way to setup a vb project?  If there is any software is available for setup a project.

Always am getting a problem for setup a VB 6 project, please Can any one help to solve my problem?

Comment: "What is best way to setup a vb6 project" has been answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23836/what-is-the-best-simple-install-system-for-xp-vista

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been using [Advanced Installer](http://www.advancedinstaller.com) (for VB.NET projects, but that doesn't matter), the free version is very capable and easy to use.

But to answer your question, sounds like the package wizard has got itself in a bad state. I'd re-install VB6 in that case.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience the VB6 Package and Deployment wizard is pretty useless. I recommend you look at commercial installation software like InstallShield or Wise.

If you have Visual Studio 2002 or above, you could also try hacking a .NET setup project to install your VB6 components. It is capable of self-registering COM binaries, creating Start menu shortcuts, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the answers to these questions

- [What is the best simple install system [for VB6 programs] on Windows XP and Vista](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23836/what-is-the-best-simple-install-system-for-xp-vista)
- [What is the best choice for building windows installers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3767/what-is-the-best-choice-for-building-windows-installers)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a copy of Visual Studio?  You can use that to create installers instead.

Comment: How to create the Installer? where I have to find that one.

Answer (score 0):

You may use some other thirdparty software like [installshield](http://www.acresso.com/products/is/installshield-overview.htm) to create the setups. As far as I see they are much flexible.

[Wise installer](http://www.wise.com/Products/Installations/WiseInstallationStudio.aspx) is one of other similar products.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft is now offering a replacement for the Package and Deployment Wizard that may help you out.  **[Visual Studio Installer](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=5FBBC453-CD04-4562-A66E-5C21436E6F56&displaylang=en#filelist)**

Comment: "Now offering?"  Well if "now" was back in 2000!  Yes, it is a better solution though.