# Compiling the software problem

Tags: vb6

Using VB6

i created a software in vb6 with xp operating system, In my system, software is working perfectly. When i run my software in other system(xp operating system), it showing error as cannot find project or library, showing error in Date, Left...,

Now i moved to vista operating system, i try to run my software, It showing the same error.

How to solve this issue.

My software is running in my system, when i try to run my software other system it showing error and also i try to run my software in vista also it showing a same error.

What happen in my code. There is any system32 file problem?

How to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to also copy the controls, and referenced files to the machine running your code. Some controls and referenced files will already be on the machine, but without experience you generally will not know which files are already installed. You can look at the checked  files in the **Project|References** and **Projects|Components** dialogs to see what is included in your project. You will need to scroll through the components dialog to find all referenced files, but in the references dialog all the references are organized at the top. Also, to confirm what file(s) a machine is missing you can look at the Events log. An error with the missing file will be logged. A drawback of this approach is that you will only get one missing file at a time as the Application quits on the first missing reference encountered.

Also MarkJ and Konamiman are both correct in that the VB6 runtimes are required, although it is common for other VB6 programs to have already installed it. If you are not building  in-house applications you do not want to take anything granted and should build a complete install for your application.

Answer (score 3):

- Sounds like you need to create an installation for your VB6 project, to install the VB6 runtime and any non-standard components used. The runtime should be [present by default on Vista](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vbrun/ms788708.aspx), so it's probably non-standard components that are missing.
- Consult the answers to your [own previous question in August](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1327487/how-can-i-setup-the-vb-project), when you asked how to make an installation for a VB6 program. (Even that August question was [already a duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23836/what-is-the-best-simple-install-system-for-xp-vista).)

Answer (score 1):

The other computers must have the VB6 runtime in order to run applications generated with VB6. Maybe is this the problem?

The VB6 runtime can be donwloaded from here: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=bf9a24f9-b5c5-48f4-8edd-cdf2d29a79d5&displaylang=en

Answer (score 0):

Use the Package and Deployment Wizard to create a setup.exe.  The Wizard will automatically include all the files you might need for distribution.