# creating setup of a project in VB6.0

Tags: visual-studio, vb6, setup-project

i have created a application in VB6.0 which is connected to MySQL through ODBC connection,there are two dsn which connects to application.Now i want to create a setup of the application that i can install on any computer.but how? I tried using Package and Development wizard in VB but it gives me error "access denied ieframe.dll" something like that while installing it AND also after using that wizard,now all my forms are corrupt.I craeted new and i don't want this to happen again.Help me!!
tired googling now!!!

Comment: Check out the answers to the previous questions on VB6 deployment. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1327487/how-can-i-setup-the-vb-project and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23836/what-is-the-best-simple-install-system-for-xp-vista

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure of the version of VB6 you are running, I do know that there was an InstallSheild Light version that shipped with Visual Studio 6 Professional. It was an optional install. If you have your original installation media try looking for it. There was also Visual Studio Installer 1.1 that used to be available from Microsoft. I found a [link](http://web.archive.org/web/20080513102621/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/aa718352.aspx) on Web.Archive.org that still works. I have used this to build msi files for VB6 in the past. You need to have Visual Interdev because it gets added as project type to it.

And since you mentioned that the Package and Deployment Wizard corrupted your project, you should make a backup of your data or use some type of source control. It will be a lot less painfull to recover when problems occur.

Comment: Thank You Sir for your reply,I am really sorry I didn't stay active on this question.
I made the setup and uploaded to softpedia.
http://www.softpedia.com/get/Internet/Other-Internet-Related/Log-Circle.shtml

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I take it that the two DSNs are not relevant to this problem?

I have never seen the error "access denied ieframe.dll", but I would guess that you are trying an installation via internet explorer.  I would try creating a standard application installation.

I have to say that I am surprised to hear of "corruption" of your forms.  Do you really mean your source code?  Or this the forms in the executable.  In any case, you really should be using some form of source control.

In any case, if you want a better answer, try giving a step by step run-throught of exactly what you are doing.

Regards,

Mark

Comment: hey thanks!!.I'am really sorry I didn't stay active on this question.
But that's all rigth!!
I did R & D on this and got the setup ready.I uploaded it to softpedia.

http://www.softpedia.com/get/Internet/Other-Internet-Related/Log-Circle.shtml