# VB6 Package and deploy setup ask system restart

Tags: vb6, package, deployment, setup-deployment

I found Vb6 tools package and deployment. I used it and created a package or setup file from my running vista operating system. Later when i tried deploying it in clients computer with winxp, it asks for update of system file and ask to restart. The process never ends just ask for update and restart. how should i create setup file to avoid this problem?

Edit: 
If i create setup file in Win98 and deploy it in clients Vista or winxp then it runs fine...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a very good chance you are trying to deploy system files that you shouldn't.  Typical examples include MSVCRT components.

[You receive multiple "System files are out of date" error messages when you install a Visual Basic 6.0 application](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/831491/)

Using Win9x can mask the problem because ancient versions are packaged.  During installation either setup1 will detect that newer versions are already in place or Windows will fend them off via System File Protection.  Vista is much better at this than XP was.

Yes, the PDW is old.  For that reason you should seek out the MSKB articles on usage tips, newer information, and on manually updating the files PDW uses as guidance (its REDIST folder, VB6DEP.INI and the .DEP files that accompany many controls).

[Best practices for deploying Visual Basic 6.0 applications](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/830761) is a good generalized starting point.

Many of these sorts of issues have been answered over the years since VB6 and the PDW were released.

Answer (score 1):

The VB6 package and deployment tool is really dated.  It doesn't play well with some of the new security features.

It's probably trying to install old copies of the VB6 runtimes and then Windows is restoring its own copies.

It's been a while, but can you remove the VB6 runtime files from the files to deploy in the Package and Deployment Wizard?  If so, do so.  As long as the computer being installed on has the latest service packs it will already have the VB6 runtimes on it.

If that doesn't solve your problem then check what other system files your deployment project has in it.  In most cases you won't need to deploy any system files as modern, patched systems should have them all.  There are a few activeX controls that may not be on modern systems, but those shouldn't cause these endless restart problems.

Alternatively, try another install technology.  You could create a setup project in modern versions of Visual Studio.  Alternatively there are some very good open-source and commercial products.

I've used this one quite successfully in the past:
http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page

Comment: I am bit confused in this "It's probably trying to install old copies of the VB6 runtimes and then Windows is restoring its own copies." as if i make setup in 98 and install in xp then it works

Comment: So what's happening then is it is trying to install some Visa-specific file your setup included onto your XP machine.  The file is probably not compatible with XP and is causing problems.  Again, I say remove the VB6 runtime files from your setup, if that doesn't work try removing other system files from your setup until you figure out which one is the problem.  Alternatively, just use your 98 build :)

Comment: Are there any other files in your setup other then the VB6 runtime files and your own compiled files?

Comment: +1 Here's a question about good install packages for VB6 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23836/what-is-the-best-simple-install-system-for-xp-vista Microsoft also released a free replacement for the package and deployment wizard, **Visual Studio Installer 1.1**. I am not sure whether it's still available.

Comment: Visual Studio Installer 1.1 is no longer available for download on Microsoft's website. I recommend choosing another install package. This question has a good list http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23836/what-is-the-best-simple-install-system-for-xp-vista