# VB6 app: rich textbox control

Tags: vb6

I have taken responsibility of a VB6 app.

I installed the VB6 IDE on one of my older machines.  When I compile the app and copy the .exe to client machines, the Rich Textbox control breaks the app and causes a run-time error.

How important is it what machine you compile an app on?  Is it possible that the app is expecting a control with a different ID and therefore there is a run-time error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to deploy the Rich Textbox control `richtx32.ocx` to the client machines. [These tables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vbasic/ms788708) show it is not part of Windows, you need to deploy it yourself.

- You might want to [create](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23836/what-is-the-best-simple-install-system-for-xp-vista) an [install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3767/what-is-the-best-choice-for-building-windows-installers) for your program.
- You could look into [using a manifest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/465882/generate-manifest-files-for-registration-free-com) so that you can just copy your program and its dependencies (like `richtx32.ocx`).
- You could just manually copy the OCX file and use [`regsvr32`](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/regsvr32.mspx) to register the OCX. This will quickly become unmanageable if you have more dependencies or many machines to deploy onto.

Comment: Don't just copy these sorts of libraries and manually register them.  Part of shared component library registration involves updating a usage count that uninstall processes look at to determine whether something else still needs the library.  Either use isolation or else create a proper installation package.