# Running VB6 applications without having installed VB6

Tags: vb6, installation

My problem is I have to install VB6 on client's computers if I want to run my VB6 applications.  Actually the version of VB6 I have, can not make setup file.  So I just make a link to the exe file manually.
Is there any way that I donot have to install VB6, could just copy a few files and the application could run?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a simple install system for VB6 on XP/Vista?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23836/how-to-create-a-simple-install-system-for-vb6-on-xp-vista)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a simple install system for VB6 on XP/Vista and newer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23836/how-to-create-a-simple-install-system-for-vb6-on-xp-vista-and-newer)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to run VB 6 applications (even when compiled to an EXE), your clients will have to have the VB 6 runtime installed on their machines. You can download the latest version [here](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=24417) and install it manually for testing purposes, but don't try and roll out an application like that.

If your version of VB 6 didn't come with the Setup and Deployment Wizard (I thought they all did?), then you should look into creating your own installer package using third-party tools.

I highly recommend [Inno Setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php), which is completely free and works great for VB 6 applications. I've used it many times myself. The website even provides [specific instructions for creating an installer for a VB 6 application](http://www.jrsoftware.org/iskb.php?vb). It creates a single EXE that contains your installer--just double-click it and go!

But there are many other options to create your own installer. The important thing is that you *definitely* want to create an installer to automate the process of installing the support files. Trying to toss a few files into the system folders here and there yourself is a terrible idea, very prone to error and resulting in a lot of support calls from your customers.

Comment: The VB6 runtimes have been a protected part of the OS for some time now, since perhaps Win2K SP3.  Unless you have to support Win9x there is little to be gained by packaging them with your VB6 programs.  The protection is more aggressive in Vista and later because faulty installers can often overlay good versions with bad.

Answer (score 2):

If your app only has an Exe (and not any class libraries (ie activex dlls etc)) then you just need the VB6 runtime (rather than the VB6 studio) rolled out to the client machines.

If you have DLLs in the app they need to be registered, so you're probably looking at least at doing a simple MSI installer.

The VB6 runtime is available here: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=24417

Its very difficult to get away with less than this - essentially your exe would have to self install - set the runtime up and do any registrations that are required.

Answer (score 1):

You can run a vb6 app without installing the runtime usually by just including msvbvm60.dll

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by including?  Just copy it in the application file location?

Comment: Yes, just include it in the same directory as the executable.