# Looking for good vb6 installer

Tags: vb6, installation

I'm still selling vb6 application that runs great: now i need a real good installer for So win-xp to win-10. 
Most problem are in user permission.

Anyone can suggest me one? tnx

Comment: If you have user permission issues a lot of factors may be at play.  One is that creating a safe per-user install for VB6 programs takes extra effort, another is the issue of writable filesystem and registry locations.  No single utility will address of these matters, and those that can help require knowledge and planning.

Comment: See other questions about VB6 installs e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23836/how-to-create-a-simple-install-system-for-vb6-on-xp-vista-and-newer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

InnoSetup (free) or InstallShield, Wise (not free).

Caution: avoid CIS - Cyber Installer Suite (because isn't longer developed)

Comment: Inno Setup. There is a VB6 Add In that will generate the INNO script which will include the VB6 run time modules and controls used by the VB6 program you want to create the setup for: https://sourceforge.net/projects/innotoolbarvb6/ There is an Inno forum here also. Excellent product and both are free.

Comment: Not a fan, it is too easy to create or copy/paste bad scripts that can result in your setup breaking other applications.  Fine in the right hands perhaps, but I am sick of cleaning up after messes caused by Inno usage.