# How to publish a Visual Basic 6 project from Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: visual-studio, vb6, publishing, vb6-migration

Is it possible to load, compile and publish / package a Visual Basic 6 project using the latest Visual Studio?

Comment: No, it is not. You can let the VB upgrade wizard try to convert the VB6 project to VB.NET (I think the wizard is still packaged with VS) but it'll no longer be VB6 (and if you've used lots of custom OLE/COM components in the VB, good *luck* with the upgrade wizard making much progress with it)

Comment: No it is not. The questions under the [`vb6-migration` tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/vb6-migration/info) are about how to convert VB6 into a .Net language. There was an upgrade wizard in earlier versions of Visual Studio but it was far from perfect. I believe it is not present in Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Nope, the last VS version shipped with the upgrade wizard was VS2008. Tbh, I've never used it _(except once or twice to test it)_ and I wouldn't recommend it even if it was still available.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed I've used the upgrade Wizard a number of times and though it is imperfect it has its place and can be quite useful once you get used to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it is not possible. There was an upgrade wizard in earlier versions of Visual Studio but it was far from perfect.

See [the `vb6-migration` tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/vb6-migration/info) for more information on methods to migrate VB6 code to a .Net language.

Comment: I don't want to migrate the project. Just be able to package and implement it on Windows 7 and 10 machines (legacy system the company does not want to get rid off yet until a new system comes along). We have to live with it. Thanks anyway

Comment: Can I check I understand correctly? You have a VB6 desktop application, and you need to provide it onto user machines? If that's true you could try using the 'package and deployment wizard' which came with VB6. If that's no good for you, check some of the options in questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23836/how-to-create-a-simple-install-system-for-vb6-on-xp-vista-and-newer)