# How do I create an installer exe with system ocx and dlls for a VB6 exe?

Tags: vb6

This question may seem really dumb, my apologies for having very minimal programming experience. We just need to make an inventory system exe given to us run and "work" on some computers.

The exe file itself is an inventory system made using Visual Basic 6. It runs fine on computers that have visual basic 6 installed.

However, on computers without VB6, we encounter crashes. The exe's themselves run fine but as soon as we perform something (logging in/clicking buttons/etc.), we get runtime errors 339. On one machine it says, **"Component 'MSCOMCT2.OCX' or one of its dependencies not correctly registered: a file is missing or invalid.** on another machine, we have a similar error but points to MSFLXGRD.OCX

I figured these problems may be caused by missing system files/dependencies and we need to first install those. How do I make an installer wizard (similar to those Windows app installers that installs system files alongside the actual app) for installing these missing dependencies?

Comment: VB6 Comes with Package and Deployment Wizard. Addins menu - Addin Manager - Package and Deployment Wizard. Then Addin menu - Package and Deployment Wizard. Both VB6 and the setup have to be run as Admin.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a simple install system for VB6 on XP/Vista and newer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23836/how-to-create-a-simple-install-system-for-vb6-on-xp-vista-and-newer)

Answer (score 1):

You could do a lot worse than the free ***[Inno Setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php)***. I've used it for many VB6 projects and it's never failed me. There's a learning curve but it's a very flexible package.

Comment: Inno works, but unless you know what you are doing and are hypervigilent it can do more harm than good.  Don't just try to copy "recipe" scripts you find on the web.  Poor Inno-created setups cause problems that are hard to track down and fix.

Answer (score 0):

I used to use (and contributed to) the [WiX](http://wixtoolset.org/) toolkit for this purpose.

This will build a standard `.msi` installer for you. Start with the `heat` program which will inspect your software and generate much of the WiX project for you, be sure to use the `-svb6` option.

You will need to source the appropriate [merge modules for VB6](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=5883) as well, which will provide the components you are missing.